# How fix 'Error while running `getDataFromTree` Network error: localStorage is not defined'?

Tags: passport.js, google-oauth, next.js, apollo-client

Everythings works but I keep getting: Error while running getDataFromTree Network error: localStorage is not defined. I tried conditionals to only send req from client but it did'nt work. All the requests seem to be coming from server.

I'm using google Oauth and passport for authentication in NextJS

Should I create authLink from a different file? Any clue?

Usefull links:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication/
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo

I've tried to conditional logic to only send req from client but then, logic stops working. Looks like most of nextJS reqest are from serverside.

```
 let apolloClient = null

    const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {

    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ? Bearer ${token} : "",
       }
      }
   });

    function create(initialState) {
    // Check out https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/4611 if you want to use the AWSAppSyncClient
    const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined'

    console.log(isBrowser);
    return new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: isBrowser,
    ssrMode: !isBrowser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
    link: authLink.concat(new createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql', // Server URL (must be absolute)
    credentials: 'same-origin', // Additional fetch() options like credentials or headers
    // Use fetch() polyfill on the server
    fetch: !isBrowser && fetch
    })),
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
    })
    }

    export default function initApollo(initialState) {
    // Make sure to create a new client for every server-side request so that data
    // isn't shared between connections (which would be bad)
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return create(initialState)
    }

    // Reuse client on the client-side
    if (!apolloClient) {
    apolloClient = create(initialState)
    }

    return apolloClient
    }
```

I need apollo to send cookies with every request, so my react component can find if the user is logged in.

It's breaking my head, any help appreciated. Thank you in advance.